# Unable to access SharePoint when VPN client is connected

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, administration, ssl

My organisation has SharePoint 2013 on prem. The site runs good on all client workstations but when user is connected to external network using VPN Client, SharePoint is not accessible. It gives a could not connect error. I tried turning the firewall on and off but no help. Is it something to do with SSL configuration? Other clients like Citrix do not reproduce this scenario.

Comment: In order to assist can you provide more details please?  What VPN is it?  Can you resolve the name via DNS when you ping?

Comment: do you have any proxy settings in IE?
did you try to use the host files?
how you accessing the sharepoit FQDN or just server name & port number?
do you have a work laptop and try on it?